# What's the difference between single processor or dual processor SQL Server 2008?

Tags: cpu, sql-server-2008

I am little bit confused about single core processor based SQL server or dual processor based SQL server.

We are planning to purchase SQL server 2008 Standard R2.

People are asking whether it is for single processor or dual processor. So, what's the difference between them?

If I've installed a single processor based SQL, then what happens?

My server has 2 quad core processors.

Comment: Have you read [Maximum Number of Processors Supported by the Editions of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do primarily with licensing. If you only purchase a license for a single CPU version and install it on a machine with 4 CPUs available, then it will only take advantage of 1 of the 4 CPUs, leaving 3 CPUs either wasted or usable for other tasks. This allows Microsoft to provide the same quality product at different price points. This let's smaller businesses that may not need the heavy lifting of a 12 core server behind their database to afford the same product and then upgrade later if the need and funding are great enough.

Comment: It's also important to note that Microsoft licences by the number of physical sockets, not the number of logical cores.

Comment: do it any compliance issue if i will use single processor SQL